# Trouble chaining together foreach and if/then/else in Powershell

Tags: powershell, regex

I have a text document containing 80 filenames of a similar format. The last 4 digits of each filename indicates its subdirectory location, for example:

`wheat_bread_12345678.doc` will always be located in `\\\\emcfiler\user\grains\56\78`;
`wheat_bread_12346942.doc` will always be located in `\\\\emcfiler\user\grains\69\42`

I'm using foreach to go through the file and then using if/then to match the filename to its directory and copy it elsewhere.

Instead of finding each file and matching it to the folder though, my script is looking for each file in the directory derived from last filename in the text document. e.g the last filename is `wheat_bread_12348723.doc` and the script is trying to find every file in `\\\\emcfiler\user\grains\87\23`.

Here is my script and one of the (79) errors:

```ps
$f = Get-Content \\\\emcfiler\user\ace\lax_brd.txt

foreach ($file in $f) {

if ($f -match ".*_\d{4,4}(\d\d)(\d\d)\.doc") {

$sourcePath = "\\\\emcfiler\user\grains\" + "$($matches[1])\$($matches[2])\" + $file

$destinationPath = "\\\\emcfiler\user\new_grains\"
Copy-Item $sourcePath $destinationPath
} 

else 

{
Write-Error "Can't find folder path from $f"
}

}
```

Error:

> Copy-Item : Cannot find path '\\emcfiler\user\grains\87\23\wheat_bread_12345678.doc' because it does not exist.

Comment: you seem to have fallen into a common trap - you used poorly a chosen name for your $Var in the `foreach` loop. note that you use `$f` [the array of strings] in your `if` test - and SHOULD have used the `$File` variable. i would rename your `$f` to something meaningful like `$FileList`.

Comment: Ok. So I will need to look into automatic variables for PS.

Comment: **_no_** ...  you need to pay attention to _what is in each variable_. the easiest way is to do that is to give them meaningful names. you used `$f` [a REALLY poorly named variable] for what needed to be ONE file. you have the array named `$f` [bad name!!!] and the individual file named `$file` ... and then used the wrong one in your code. ONLY use the `$file` inside the `foreach` loop.

Comment: I renamed $f to $filelist and corrected the if line: if ($file -match ".*_\d{4,4}(\d\d)(\d\d)\.doc" and the Write-Error line to: Write-Error "Can't determine folder from filename $file." and it worked. I will be more careful, thanks for showing me what to practice on more.

Comment: kool! you are most welcome & i am glad to know you got it working as needed ... [*grin*]